# В лабораторной работе дана программа,нужно исправить ее работу,проблема в том что я просто не понимаю что она должна сделать

Tags: c

Вот программа

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>

  main() 
 {
 float     tr[4][2]; 
 float     xe,ye,xa,ya,xb,yb,xc,yc,xd,yd,a,b,c,d,f,h;
 int       i; 

printf("Введите координаты параллелограмма\n"); 
for (i=0; i<4; i++) 
  {
    printf("Координаты: %d-й точки: x=",i+1); 
    scanf("%f", &tr[i][0]); 
    printf("y="); 
    scanf("%f", &tr[i][1]); 
  } 
xa=tr[0][0]; 
ya=tr[0][1]; 
xb=tr[1][0]; 
yb=tr[1][1]; 
xc=tr[2][0]; 
yc=tr[2][1]; 
xd=tr[3][0]; 
yd=tr[3][1]; 
printf("%f, %f\n %f %f\n %f %f\n %f 
 %f\n",xa,ya,xb,yb,xc,yc,xd,yd); 
a=sqrt((xa-xb)*(xa-xb)+(ya-yb)*(ya-yb)); 
b=sqrt((xb-xc)*(xb-xc)+(yb-yc)*(yb-yc)); 
c=sqrt((xc-xd)*(xc-xd)+(yc-yd)*(yc-yd)); 
d=sqrt((xd-xa)*(xd-xa)+(yd-ya)*(yd-ya)); 
f=sqrt((xa-xc)*(xa-xc)+(ya-yc)*(ya-yc)); 
h=sqrt((xb-xd)*(xb-xd)+(yb-yd)*(yb-yd)); 
if((a+b>f)&&(b+c>h)&&(d+c>f)&&(a+d>h)) 
  { 
    xe=(xa+xc)/2; 
    ye=(ya+yc)/2; 
    printf("xe=%f, ye=%f",xe,ye); 
  } 
else
  { 
    printf(" Данный параллелограмм((%f, %f),(%f, %f),(%f, %f)," 
    "(%f, %f) вырожденый\n",xa,ya,xb,yb,xc,yc,xd,yd);
  }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Считать параллелограмм, вычислить длины его сторон и диагоналей, проверить, что параллелограмм существует и вывести точку пересечения диагоналей.

Значительных ошибок в коде не вижу. Только кривизна написания. Впрочем, нигде не проверяется, что вводимая фигура параллелограмм. Работает одинаково для любого выпуклого четырёхугольника.

Comment: То есть добавить пвроверку на то является ли фигура параллелограммом и все будет работать так как должно? Ну и сам код подправить немного

Comment: @GUESS, ну, возможно. Не я ж тебе это задание давал.